# How touse iSCSI HA with Windows Server

Tags: windows, failovercluster

I have one Windows Server 2012 standard, one Windows Server 2016 standard, two QNAP.

We planning to store all files in QNAP and create VM in Windows Server for clustering.

We want to have high avalability file server with these four pieces of equipment.

How to achieve this?

Comment: The more effort you put into formulating the question, the more useful answers you get. Currently it is very bad. Which QNAP model you are talking about? Did you read its manual? What part you have not understand in it?

Comment: You can look into mfsBSD, a lightweight FreeBSD-based distro, that fits perfectly onto QNAP embedded flash drives. FreeBSD brings you with `ctld` (ISCSI target daemon), as well as `hastd` (block device synchronization), `carp` (VRRP / sharing virtual IPs), and `ifstated` (running commands during failovers, promotion/demotion/...). Not to mention zfs-on-root. Been using QNAP providing with HA LUN devices for years now, works perfectly.